# My VBA code is not reacting when a condition has been met

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA in Microsoft Access. I want the code to run before the user completes each entry of "downtime". I am trying to make sure that the value of a box is not a negative number. The box actually holds a formula. I don't know if that matters but, I thought I would mention that. I want to check the result of the calculation (the value that is showing in that box) and if it is less than 0, I want a MsgBox to pop up. My code is doing nothing. No error, no pop-up, no warnings.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If (Me.RunningTotal.Value < 0) Then
        MsgBox (RunningTotal & "Please check your downtime.")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried using the "RunningTotal" in brackets as well with no luck. I have also tried beforeupdat as well as afterupdate.

Comment: The `BeforeUpdate` event won't fire on the calculated control.  You say the user completes entry of _downtime_  - add the code to the control that the user manually completes.

Comment: That was the first place I tried the code. I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that as well. I've tried putting the code in the user entry box, the form itself and the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I had to put the code in the user's data entry box AND as an "after update" since the calculation wouldn't happen until after the entry has been made. Thank you, Darren, for your help. :) Here is the code that works.

```
*Private Sub MinutesDown_AfterUpdate()
    If (Me.RunningTotal < 0) Then
        MsgBox (RunningTotal & "Please check your downtime.")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub*
```

Comment: `Cancel = True` does nothing in this code. The AfterUpdate event does not have a `Cancel` argument. You may wish to consider adding `Option Explicit` to the top of every code module, so it will highlight undeclared variables when you compile (Here `Cancel` is undeclared.)